# Catching F.52 spool job number created during batch input execution?

Tags: abap

The transaction F.52 generates an printout when it is started with the  function. The printout is redirected to the SAP spool.

After the report (RFSZIS00, started within TA F.52) has finished, the SAP spool job number is displayed for information purposes. The dynpro-screen (SAPLSPRI / 0200) with the information is displayed automatically.

I need to run this transaction automatically for multiple ledgers as a batch input session.
But I cannot find a way to save the corresponding spool job number for each ledger.

Does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Regards

Comment: In case your goal is to get the data of the table (ALV) displayed by F.52, instead of generating the spool you may intercept the data (no display) and process it directly in your own program.

Comment: In the batchinput return table should have the message with spool number

Comment: @I.B.N. No, the spool number is not in the return table. It's not a message, it's a dynpro. I've checked this with a batch input recording.

Comment: `when it is started with the function` what kind of function? Give the code. Show the screen where this dynpro is displayed

Answer (score 0):

Batch Input is "blind", it's able to input values in fields fixed before running it, but is not able to see and return what is displayed (dynpro field values), except the messages.

I don't know if there's a specific answer for `F.52` but generally speaking, you may approximate which spool number has been generated, by filtering the table of spool requests, `TSP01`, by date, time, user, name of spool containing a part of the program name.

As you have a batch input session which calls `F.52` once per ledger, you have to create a custom transaction and program to insert right after each `F.52` call, which will extract the last generated spool number by querying `TSP01`. Maybe the Batch Input Session is generated, so you might want to determine which ledger corresponds to the processed ledger, one solution is maybe to use the User Memory (ABAP statement [`GET PARAMETER`](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abapget_parameter.htm)). You get the `Parameter ID` of the ledger by pressing the `F1` key on the dynpro field.

Comment: `which will extract the last generated spool number by querying TSP01` it may not work if the commit to TSP01 is done in a deferred manner